# When to use getters/setters and when to safely omit them?

Tags: ember.js

According to http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/ it is required to access properties using getters and setters:

> When accessing the properties of an object, use the get and set accessor methods.
>
> Make sure to use these accessor methods; otherwise, computed properties won't recalculate, observers won't fire, and templates won't update.

I understand that it is needed to use setters when changing property to let Ember know about the change so it can update bindings, but what about reading properties?

Example from http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/

```
App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
  say: function(thing) {
    var name = this.get('name');
    alert(name + " says: " + thing);
  }
});

var yehuda = App.Person.create({
  name: "Yehuda Katz"
});

yehuda.say("Yes");
```

In the example above, `this.get('name')` is used to access property `name`, however method `say` is defined as a property of class `App.Person` and is accessed directly by dot notation. While there is a distinctive usage difference between method and property, in JavaScript, there's no difference in implementation of both. The example still works if I replace `this.get('name')` by `this.name`.

1. Are there any implementation differences in Ember regarding methods and properties of object?
2. Is it always safe to access methods directly?
3. Must all properties including computed properties be always accessed by getter? If not, when is it safe to access properties directly?

I definitely want to stick to best practise here, which is to use getter/setter every time, but I'd like to understand the internals of Ember.js :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. The definition of a method or a property in Ember is the same as in Vanilla JavaScript, but they are resolved different in Ember. You are not working with POJOs. Every time you extend from a Route/Controller/View, you are adding the Ember layer that processes methods and properties differently.
2. No, is not always safe. In your case it is because it is overly simple.
3. Yes, always access properties with `get`.

User interaction with your app is what causes changes in the properties of your objects, we handle those interactions with events. When an event in Ember is fired, it is not resolved immediately, instead it is put in a priority queue and resolved at a later time.

Properties are updated and read in an asynchronous form, if you access them directly using `this` there is no guarantee that you'll get the most up to date value.

Check: [Managing Asynchrony](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/managing-asynchrony/)

> When you make a change to a property in Ember, it does not immediately propagate that change. Instead, it invalidates any dependent properties immediately, but queues the actual change to happen later.

So, when you change the value of a property, this is roughly what happens:

1. A property is changed
2. All dependent properties are invalidated
3. Queues the actual change for later
4. Wait for any other event handlers, for the current user, to finish
5. Flush the changes queue

   - Until here, the property is actually updated (and `this` would work as usual)

Imagine you use `this` to read a property, but some other event occurs that changes its value. The new value won't be available until the queue is flushed, but `this` reads immediately the property and returns the value of a property that is scheduled to be updated soon. You get stale data. The methods `get` and `set` manage this asynchrony for you and guarantee fresh values always.

When you have only one property, in the whole app, this asynchronous mechanism won't be noticed.

There are many different queues in Ember, and the fundamental mechanism behind all this is [the run loop](http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/run-loop/).

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, now I understand that I need to access properties always with get/set methods. Ad 2. Can you please clarify when it is safe and unsafe to access methods with `this`? Do methods need to be accessed by getters in any scenarios? I think it would lead to `this.get('methodA').call(this)`

Comment: The behavior has changed in newer Ember versions and you can now safely use POJO getters, except with `ObjectProxy` properties: https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.9.0/object-model/classes-and-instances/#toc_accessing-object-properties