# this.propertyName VS this.get('propertyName') in an ember component

Tags: ember.js

I'm relatively new in EmberJS and I'm trying to make sure I understand what is happening under the covers. 
I understand that for a computed property I need to use this.get('propertyName') to calculate and get the property. If we are just talking about normal properties with a value what is the difference between using this.propertyName vs this.get('propertyName')?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  data: ['foobar', 'foo', 'bar'],
  didInsertElement() {
    let data = null;
    data = this.get('data');
    // VS
    data = this.data;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is already answered at length here [When to use getters/setters and when to safely omit them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23681736/when-to-use-getters-setters-and-when-to-safely-omit-them)

(I can not mark this question as "possible duplicate" yet)

> The definition of a method or a property in Ember is the same as in
>   Vanilla JavaScript, but they are resolved differently in Ember. You
>   are not working with POJOs. Every time you extend from a
>   Route/Controller/View, you are adding the Ember layer that processes
>   methods and properties differently.

It is not recommended to access properties directly. In very simple cases it might be ok, and you get the same value, but in more complicated cases you might get different values.

PS: Computed properties has to be always accessed via get(), because that is the moment they are re-calculated. I think Ember caches the values somehow, but I am still a newbie too :)